# How to implement UICollectionView into UITableviewCell using swift either add tableview horizontally?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling

Hello I have tried to use UICollectionView into UITableViewCell but it didn't work, I have to show in each UITableViewCell by adding dynamically multiple views but it scroll horizontally. Please help me I am beginner in swift.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326547/use-uicollectionview-inside-uitableviewcell) technically but since it is in swift and that question is in obj-c I am going to let it pass

Comment: Also, Read up [This tutorial](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/).

Comment: Ok NSNoob thank you so mch, i will try to implement but I want in swift all this tutorial in obj-c

Comment: I know but I think you are more interested in knowing the logic of how it works, you can learn that from that tutorial as well.

Comment: yes thats write NSNoob,\ but i have alrady tried for it i have implement collection view into tableview cell but it doesn't scroll ,so thats why i need swift logic

Comment: Hmm then you should add your implementation to your question. Then people will be able to help you fix that issue precisely.

Comment: in attributes inspector for collection view there is scroll direction which might be horizontal in your case, change it to vertical.

Comment: yes i have did this but still not working is it possible to add collection view into uitableviewcell using swift

Comment: Updated question with tag

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a horizontal picker view. Try this [AKPickerView](https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView-Swift)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take tableview and take tableviewcell in the tableview. After this you have to take collectionview in tableviewcell. If you manage this in proper way you can get your answer.If not you can refer my code from below link.I set my code in tester.zip.You can download this from below link.
 https://github.com/Mirant123/MIke/commit/91226c72f3f88b3201803e6b607f77f749c8b413